# How to add new values to key in a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

If I had a sample dict:

```
mydict = {1:{2:'A'}}
```

how can I add new data to key `1` so that it can be like:

```
mydict = {1:{2:'A'},{3:'B'}}
```

When I do `mydict.update({3:'B'})`

I get:
`{1: {2: 'A'}, 3: 'B'}` not `{1: {2: 'A'}, {3: 'B'}}`

If I try `.update` using the same key it just replaces the data:

`mydict.update({1:{3:'B'}})` becomes
`{1: {3: 'B'}}`

Comment: Do you understand how dictionaries work? With what key are you associating `{3 : 'B'}`?

Comment: can I not have key `1` associate to `{2:'A'}` and `{3:'B'}`?

Comment: 1 key, 1 value.

Comment: @wrneoin You have a key-dict pair. You need a key-list of dict pair if you want to add multiple separate dicts.

Comment: You want create a new dict-type `one--> many`

Comment: @wrneoin: Do you want `{1: [{2:'A'},{3:'B'}] }` or `{1: {2:'A', 3:'B'} }`? It matters.

Answer (score 1):

There already have a good library for you:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)
d['person']['name']='frank'
d['person']['age']='age'
```

and then you can easily get the data from your 2 key! like:

```
print d['person']['name']
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `mydict.update({3:'B'})` you are updating the wrong dictionary.

It looks like you want to update the dictionary in `mydict[1]`

This is assuming you actually want a result of `{1: {2: 'A', 3: 'B'}}` as your example `{1: {2: 'A'}, {3: 'B'}}` is not valid python.

So try `mydict[1].update({3:'B'})`

Comment: Glad to hear it. Don't forget to upvote and accept this answer if that solves your problem :)

Comment: @wrneoin I don't think you know what you want. Do you want to add an entry to the existing dict? Or add a completely separate dict? Your question and your comment conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add

```
 mydict[1].update({3:'B'})
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
 mydict ={2:'a',3:'b'}
 d={1:mydict}
 print (d)
 {1: {2: 'a', 3: 'b'}}
 
 to update more key:values you can add to mydict
```

Answer (score 0):

A single key can only refer to a single item
If you want to want a key to store two different items , make the key refer to another dict

As in

```
sub_dict = {2:'A' , 3:'B'}
my_dict = {1:sub_dict}
```

The different items can be accessed as follows

```
print(my_dict[1][2]) #this prints A
print(my_dict[1][3]) #this prints B
```

Hope this helps :)